# Open the VC by pressing a button from the XIB

Tags: swift, xib, viewcontroller

Help me please.
There is a map with markers, clicking on them brings up a XIB = UIVIew, there is a button in it, you need to click the button to open the viewController

Comment: Are you using Google Maps SDK for this?

Comment: No, I am using apple maps

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MarkerVC")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: So impressed you figured out what was being asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
let viewController = YourViewController(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: nil)
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If the VC is from XIB, use the above.